# Unable to change background color on UICollectionView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uibackgroundcolor

I'm writing my first iOS app and I seam to be having some problems in changing the backgroundColor of a UICollectionView.

The app has a navigation controller and certain views. Initially, I was able to change the color in my AppDelegate implementation file:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        feedsList = [[FeedsListTVC alloc] init];

        rootNC = [[RootNC alloc] init];
        rootNC.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:feedsList, nil];

        self.window.rootViewController = rootNC;

        return YES;
    }
```

Using

```
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I was able to change the background color on all my views.
However, I decided to add one more view (the UICollectionView) and to set it as the main view. 
So I changed the AppDelegate to this:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        CollectionViewLayoutCVL *collectionViewLayout = [[CollectionViewLayoutCVL alloc] init];
        self.viewController = [[MainViewControllerCVC alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];

        rootNC = [[RootNC alloc] init];
        rootNC.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, nil];

        self.window.rootViewController = rootNC;

        return YES;
    }
```

From my point of view this looks mostly the same.

I also tried this inside the implementation file of the UICollectionView but this changes the color of the view controller not the color of the Collection's view as far as I can tell:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well written post, and great response.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor];`

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I can't believe I missed this. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works but self.view.backgroundColor does not? I'd expect view and collection view to refer to the same instance.

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor works too, but if i take a wild guess why u cant see it , it is probably coz the collectionview is over the self.view. and the collectionview's color is opague white or smthing like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *redView = [UIView new];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
_collectionView.backgroundView = redView;
```

Comment: where were you heading with this?

Comment: This actually works. The collectionView.backgroundColor doesn't work. But this does the trick. I don't get it?

Comment: Just a vague guess..may be backgroun view layer is above the background color.

Answer (score 1):

### Objective-C

#### No Color

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

#### Any color

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];    
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

---

### Swift

#### No Color

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

#### Any color

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
```